# What's the best resource to learn about Android ANRs and particularly ANR logs

Tags: android, android-framework, android-anr-dialog

I know some about Android ANR, what can cause them and what to do to avoid them, and still most ANR logs I see in the field make little to no sense to me, tend to have a bunch of process listed and not particular information about what they were doing at the time, sometimes stuck in some mundane part of the frameworks, descriptions being vague etc...

Do you guys know of an extensive documentation to learn more about all types of ANR and how to truly track down the cause of one?

I'd take any online documentation and even seminars, as this seems like the biggest area of darkness for me and most devs I know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about checking out this document?
    http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: Yeah that's basically ground zero.